# Express : the same controller works on 1 route, but doesn't work on the other

Tags: node.js, express

I have a controller that check if the project exists:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Project = require ('../models/Project');
const { handleError,ErrorHandler } = require('../helpers/error');


exports.checkProject = (req,res,next) =>
{
    Project.findById(req.params.projectId, (err) =>{
        if (err) {
            err= new ErrorHandler(404, "Project not found");
            return next (err);
            }
            else {
             return next();
            }
        }, (err) => next (err))
        .catch ((err) => next (err))
        };
```

When I call it on /project router it works perfectly well:

```
projectRouter.route ('/:projectId')


.put(projectController.checkProject,projectController.updateProject)
```

However, when I call it on '/:projectId/issues' it's not working if I input the wrong projectId:

```
projectRouter.route ('/:projectId/issues')

.get(projectController.checkProject, issueController.getAllIssues)
```

I really don't want to check projectId in IssuesContoller everytime I do any operation with 'Issues". Is there any elegant solution to this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Describe a specific URL and what the behavior is and what you expect the behavior to be.

Comment: I need to check if projectId exists for both routes : /project/projectId & project/projectId/issues:

Comment: checkPorject middleware works for /project/projectId, but doesn't work for project/projectId/issues. Whenever a wrong projectID is passed in project/projectId/issues it throws 500

Comment: Probably a different issue, but why are you passing two callbacks to `Project.findById()` AND using `.catch()`.  That can't all be correct.